# VSTS dotnet run step does not find build from previous step

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, runtime-error

I have the following successful `dotnet build` release pipeline step configured:

```
Task version: 2.*
Display name: dotnet build
Command: build
Path to project(s): **/AppConsole.csproj
Arguments:
```

It is immediately following by a failing `dotnet run` step:

```
Task version: 2.*
Display name: dotnet run
Command: run
Path to project(s): **/AppConsole.csproj
Arguments:
```

Which exits with the message:

```
[command]C:\agent_dply\_work\_tool\dotnet\dotnet.exe run C:\agent_dply\_work\r40\a\Testing\Tester\AppConsole.csproj
Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in  C:\agent_dply\_work\r40\a.
Or pass the path to the project using --project
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\agent_dply\_work\_tool\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : C:\agent_dply\_work\r40\a\Testing\Tester\AppConsole.csproj
```

How do I tell the `dotnet` command where the project is when running under VSTS? I've tried, as it recommends, using the `--project` flag, but it gives similar errors.

Comment: I'm curious why you even want to run on the build server anyway?

Comment: I want to run a console app which processes some files in preparation for the next step, which would be dotnet test.

Comment: try to set the working directory of "dotnet run" to the directory where your project is located in

Comment: `dotnet run` implies a build though, do you need the manual build step?

Comment: It's build pipeline or release pipeline? (from your logs it look like release)

Comment: Sorry, just updated: release

Comment: @MattW try this: `Path to projects(s): $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/**/AppConsole.csproj`

Comment: I would have thought that **/AppConsole.csproj would have resolved that path as well, no?

Comment: What is strange is that only the dotnet run appears unable to find the csproj. Does it behave differently on the server than locally? Should I expect the build output to be somewhere other than where the artifact folder is? Am I naive in expecting the artifact folder to be the location where the build takes place?

Comment: dotnet-run is usually not called like it is in the logged task above. try to not use the dotnet-task in this case and just use commandline-task with "dotnet run" and set the working directory to the directory where your project is located it